# Australian construction cost forecasts

Tags: data-request, time-series, australia

The Australian Bureau of Statistics publishes a series of Producer Price Indexes (PPI) that include an index for housing construction costs, both for Australia as a whole and for each of the individual states.

I'm trying to find a series that I can use in conjunction with the actual PPI, in the same way that one might look at inflation forecasts together with later, empirically recorded inflation values. Specifically, I'm looking for a series that shows what the expectation was at some point in time prior to the publication of any particular quarterly index value. For example, the (hypothetical-until-found) series might show what March 2023 quarterly value of the PPI was expected back in 2021 ... or even more crudely, what the annual 2023 change was expected to be back in 2021.

Any suggestions for where I might look.